# mysql pivot for finding the timediff

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am having a problem in finding the time difference by dates in a pivot manner

This is the code that i have tried can someone suggest me where is the error

```
    Select 'user_name','2017_10_23','2017_10_24','2017_10_25'
    union all
    Select table1.* from 
    (
    select user_name,
    IF(dates="2017-10-23",Total,0)AS 2017_10_23,
    IF(dates="2017-10-24",Total,0)AS 2017_10_24,
    IF(dates="2017-10-25",Total,0)AS 2017_10_25
    from
    (
    select user_name,dates,Total
 from(select user_name,date(starttime) as dates,
TIME_FORMAT((TIMEDIFF(max(endtime),min(starttime))),'%Hh %im')
 as
 total 
from
 augustTable 
where flag=1 and date(starttime) between '2017-10-23' and '2017-10-25' and (ltrim(rtrim(matching)) not like '%SKIP%' and ltrim(rtrim(matching)) not like '%BLANK%' and ltrim(rtrim(matching)) not like '%LOW VOICE%') group by user_name,dates)a
    where user_name<>'' 
    group by dates,user_name
    )a 
    GROUP BY user_name
    )table1
```

This the output that i am getting i should not  be getting 0 values

```
+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| user_name         | 2017_10_23 | 2017_10_24 | 2017_10_25 |
+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| user_name         | 2017_10_23 | 2017_10_24 | 2017_10_25 |
| Aditya Valecha    | 06h 45m    | 0          | 0          |
| Ajinkya Surve     | 04h 51m    | 0          | 0          |
| Akhtar Ahmed      | 04h 08m    | 0          | 0          |
| Akshata Gupta     | 07h 10m    | 0          | 0          |
| Aniket Shetty     | 06h 38m    | 0          | 0          |
| Anish Koli        | 06h 44m    | 0          | 0          |
| Avani Mehta       | 08h 15m    | 0          | 0          |
| Brandon Gonsalves | 06h 10m    | 0          | 0          |
| Dhaval Nanda      | 08h 34m    | 0          | 0          |
| Faiz Sayed        | 03h 24m    | 0          | 0          |
| Ketan Shetty      | 06h 21m    | 0          | 0          |
| Kirti Mulay       | 03h 49m    | 0          | 0          |
| Manjeet Yadav     | 04h 03m    | 0          | 0          |
| Mitesh Apraj      | 0          | 07h 40m    | 0          |
```

Comment: There is no SQL error.. The query works but doesnt generate expected results.. Questions like this should include example data and expected result as text formatted tables

Comment: _**@OP**_: what do you mean by _i should not be getting 0 values_ ...???

Comment: there is values for each date